# How to convert relative path to a folder on the filesystem to an absolute path

Tags: python, linux

This might be a fairly straightforward question, but given the path:

```
~/Desktop/SomeDirectory/
```

or any other directory located in a user's home directory

How do I get the absolute path to this folder?
`os.path.abspath` just gives me the absolute path for my current working directory. But that's not what I need to work with.

Comment: [os.path.expanduser(path)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [`os.path.expanduser`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) method.